# ANSI terminal color behaves strangely

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, colors

I am encountering strange behaviour when trying to switch on and off background colors in terminal output:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "\e[48;5;203m"
printf "AAA\n"
printf "\e[0m"

printf "BBB\n"
printf "CCC\n"
```

I want `AAA` to be printed with red background, then switch off the background color, and print the next lines. However, this is how the output looks like:

[image]

## UPDATE

OK, I tried from a new terminal, and there it works as expected.
But I still have the old terminal window open, where I get the output as shown.
What is happening there? Is there some "garbage" left in the terminal, that is causing this?

I did `reset` in the old terminal window, and the output is now correct.

Comment: It works as intended on my terminal (KDE Plasma, Konsole).

Comment: Same on `xterm` (work as intended)

Comment: thank you, please see my update

Comment: Why don't you just use one command? `printf "\e[48;5;203mAAA\e[0m\nBBB\nCCC\n"` works as expected and doesn't have the issues you mention.

Comment: @terdon - because instead if `printf "AAA\n"` there is actually output coming from a command. I used simplified code for demonstration.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When `AAA\n` is printed *at the very bottom of the terminal*, the terminal needs to scroll the text and make an empty line appear at the bottom. It displays the line using the current background color, which is red. Then `BBB\n` is printed over this background, using its own background color. The new background color affects only few characters in the current line (`BBB`), but it is relevant when the next empty line appears. In effect the next line (where `CCC` is going to appear) looks normal.

When `AAA\n` is printed not at the bottom, the terminal does not need to add a line, empty space is already there. It so happens the empty space is black.

To reproduce, run your code several times until you get to the bottom of the terminal and "beyond".

The following two commands, when repeated (each one in its own terminal), give output that looks identical, until the bottom is reached:

1. ```
   printf "\e[48;5;203mAAA\n\e[0m"
   ```
2. ```
   printf "\e[48;5;203mAAA\e[0m\n"
   ```

In the second case the background gets reset *before* `\n`.

My testbed: Konsole 21.12.3, `TERM=xterm-256color`.

Comment: Exactly! when I reach the bottom of the terminal, it starts to look broken like on my screenshot. So is this a bug in the terminal emulator?

Comment: @400 I wouldn't call it a bug. The current background color affects more things: e.g. `clear` after your `printf "AAA\n"` makes the entire area turn red. And if I *had to* call one of the two behaviors "broken", I would say the not-at-the-bottom one is "broken". Apparently you would disagree. I could fix what I'd find "broken" with `tput el` just after your `printf "AAA\n"`. Truly I find neither behavior broken; I accept the fact `\n` in some circumstances results in a line of different color. Terminals are already a zoo and we need `TERM`, `tput` and e.g. ncurses to work reliably with them.

Answer (score -1):

As @Kamil Maciorowski answered, you should revert the background color *before* printing the newline.

However, that might still give you unexpected background color, depending on:

- whether there's an implicit linewrap (the text you print is wider than the terminal),
- whether you cause the terminal to scroll or not,
- the concrete choice of terminal emulator, further boiling down to:

  - whether it implements "background color erase" (bce) or not,
  - whether it (intentionally or accidentally) deviates from the standard (xterm) bce implementation.

You might be interested in https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754596 for juicy details explaining an inevitable problem with xterm's bce handling, and how VTE (GNOME Terminal etc.) intentionally changed the behavior to fix that problem in a way that doesn't cause known regressions in existing apps.